# Can a value list remember where you were last?

Tags: filemaker

In my database, users are complaining that to input data in from a value list, even though they are inputting the same, or next, value in subsequent records they have to scroll down to where the last value was in the list.

Is there a method for filemaker to remember the last value chosen in a value list and display the drop down for the value list starting (in the middle) from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just set the field to the desired value before displaying the value list. Then it will start with that value selected.